# C++14 Uniform Initialization on a Non-Aggregate

Tags: c++, c++14, uniform-initialization

I'm using Visual C++ 2013. When the class is an aggregate it is zero-initialized. When it's a non-aggregate it seems to be default-initialized and left indeterminate. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test_1
{
public:
    int i;
    void f(){};
};

class Test_2
{
public:
    int i;
    virtual void f(){};
};

int main()
{
    Test_1 t1{};
    Test_2 t2{};

    cout<<t1.i<<endl; //0
    cout<<t2.i<<endl; //-858993460

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Which compiler and which version? `{}` should be value-initialization for non-aggregates and `t2.i` should have been zero-initialized since it has no user-provided constructor.

Comment: This causes MSVC hosted on [rextester](http://rextester.com/runcode) to hang and then give similar garbage. Same thing with another [MSVC online compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/). I smell a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your compiler is doing this, it's broken.

[dcl.init.list]/p3 (all quotes are from N4140):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined
>   as follows:
>
> - If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is
>     value-initialized.
> - [...]

[dcl.init]/p8:

> To value-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is
>     user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is
>     zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for
>     default-initialization are checked, and if T has a non-trivial default
>     constructor, the object is default-initialized;
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

`Test_2` is not an aggregate, so `t2` should have been value-initialized. In turn, since `Test_2`'s default constructor is not user-provided, `t2` is supposed to be first zero-initialized (causing `t2.i` to be initialized to 0), and then the default constructor is run.

Comment: Value-initialization of non-trivial classes is indeed broken in VC++, and has always been. Sadly, there's no fix in sight, despite the fundamentally necessary nature of initialization semantics. [Here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746973/incorrect-c-11-value-initialization-for-type-with-implicitly-declared-but-non-trivial-default-constructor) is one of _many_ submitted bug reports, all closed as 'deferred' that I've seen. [In some cases, not even aggregate initialization is correct.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/956553)